# Visual Studio 2015 shows error for "Create or alter procedure"

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

I have a .sql file in my project that contains a "CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ..." statement.

Visual Studio reports this as 2 errors in the "Error List" window (see screen shot).

How can I make Studio 2015 understand and accept this modern SQL statement?

[image: Visual Studio Error Messages]

Comment: why do you want to alter the procedure? it should be create or replace procedure,

Comment: You can't use "CREATE OR ALTER" as one command, they both work only separate. Except you use SQL 2016 SP1?

Comment: How can you make VS *2015* handle a SQL SERVER *2016* command? You probably cannot.

Comment: And VS 2017 does not have a release of SSDT. Quite the conundrum, I've found. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt don't be fooled by the MS mumbo jumbo about data storage and processing. It does not have the SSDT tools.

Comment: If I can't get VS 2015 to recognize the SS 2016 command, is there a way to tell studio not to report these particular errors?